# PHP get color at last pixels of image error

Tags: php, hex, gd, getimagesize

I've made this code to get hex colors of the first pixel and the last pixel of an image.
The code for the first pixel is working, I get the HEX code.
But for the last pixel, I've an error:

```
PHP Notice:  imagecolorat(): 1,1024 is out of bounds in /var/playground/imghex.php on line 55
```

Here's my code:

```
$gradientHeight = getimagesize($res["gradient"]);
// get Positions
$im  = imagecreatefrompng($res["gradient"]);
$rgb = imagecolorat($im, 0, 0);
$r   = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g   = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b   = $rgb & 0xFF;
// store
$res["Gradient1"] = rgb2hex([$r, $g, $b]);
// get positions
print_r($gradientHeight);
$rgb2 = imagecolorat($im, $gradientHeight[0], $gradientHeight[1]);
$r2   = ($rgb2 >> 16) & 0xFF;
$g2   = ($rgb2 >> 8) & 0xFF;
$b2   = $rgb2 & 0xFF;
// store
$res["Gradient2"] = rgb2hex([$r2, $g2, $b2]);
// print
print_r($res);
```

What's wrong? I don't see any error

Comment: @FirstOne do you mean that `$rgb2 = imagecolorat($im, $gradientHeight[0] - 1, $gradientHeight[1]);
` ? because `PHP Notice:  imagecolorat(): 0,1024 is out of bounds`

Comment: Solved, thank you `:)` Please make an answer so I can upvote you and choose your answer as valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see that notice because you are using the **size** on a **0-based** index. If you have size of `1024`, you'll have positions from `0` to `1023`.

That way, you'll need to subtract `1` from it. Replace

```
$rgb2 = imagecolorat($im, $gradientHeight[0], $gradientHeight[1]);
```

with

```
$rgb2 = imagecolorat($im, $gradientHeight[0] - 1, $gradientHeight[1] - 1);
```